# Kendo Autocomplete 'clear' button is appearing beneath the input field

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-ui

I recently updated our company's Kendo jQuery version from 2020.3.915 to 2021.2.511 (I know, I know) and because we are so far behind in our version updates I am doing the process incrementally. After updating to 2021.1.224, I noted that the 'x' button to clear the input field is now rendering outside and beneath the input instead of inside of it. I've tried targeting the specific class, but since I have autocompletes in a variety of width sizes in my application, altering the style classes is just creating more work and making the 'x' appear all over the place. Does anyone have experience with this issue or know how I can fix this? Google results have rendered to close to little information on the issue.

Comment: Kendo is very finicky on their styling. Unfortunately I think you'll need to do some old school debugging. What I would do is first remove any custom styling and only reference the Kendo-UI libraries. If that renders the "x" button correctly then I would suggest incrementally adding your custom styling back. Once you find the culprit, inspect the element and find the differences. This will inevitably reveal which specific rule is causing the issue.